# Could not find the correct Provider<Movies> above this MyApp Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, bloc

So, I'm using BLoC and Provider packages in one app.
In my 'moviesprovider.dart' I am fetching some data from my API which returns a json, when app is opening first time. How can I get access to Provider.of(context) from main.dart in MultiProvider? Basically, I want to get access to the same instance of List movies, but don't know how.

The error I'm getting:

---

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MyApp Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.

---

Code:
***Main.dart***

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Movies(),
        ),
        Provider<SwipeBloc>(create: (_) {
          SwipeBloc()
            ..add(
              LoadMoviesEvent(
                movies: context.read<Movies>().movies,
              ),
            );
        }),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: User(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
      ],
      child: ...
  }
}
```

***movies_provider.dart***

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movies_recomendations/constants.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import './single_movie_provider.dart';

class Movies with ChangeNotifier {
  String plotText = "";

  List<Movie> _movies = [];

  List<Movie> get movies {
    return <Movie>[..._movies];
  }

  .....

  Future<void> fetchAndSetMovies() async {
    const url = 'http://192.168.1.142:8000/Desktop/textData.json';

    try {
      final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(url),
      );
      String source = Utf8Decoder().convert(response.bodyBytes);

      final extractedData =
          List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json.decode(source));
      final List<Movie> loadedMovies = [];

      extractedData.forEach(
        ((movieInfo) => {
              loadedMovies.add(Movie(
                id: movieInfo['id'],
                age: 12,
                countries: List<String>.from(movieInfo['country']),
                description: movieInfo['descriprion'],
                frames: movieInfo['frames'],
                genre: movieInfo['genre'],
                poster: movieInfo['poster'],
                premiereWorld: movieInfo['date'].toString(),
                ratingIMDb: movieInfo['ratingIMDb'],
                ratingKinopoisk: movieInfo['ratingKinopoisk'],
                title: movieInfo['title'][1],
                ifSeries: movieInfo['ifSeries'],
                dateTo: movieInfo['dateTo'].toString(),
                isFavourite: true,
                seasons: movieInfo['seasons'],
              )),
            }),
      );
      _movies = loadedMovies;
      notifyListeners();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('error');
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

***Swipe_event.dart***

```
part of 'swipe_block.dart';

abstract class SwipeEvent extends Equatable {
  const SwipeEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadMoviesEvent extends SwipeEvent {
  final List<Movie> movies ;

  LoadMoviesEvent({
    required this.movies,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [movies];
}

class SwipeLeftEvent extends SwipeEvent {
  final Movie movie;

  SwipeLeftEvent({
    required this.movie,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [movie];
}

class SwipeRightEvent extends SwipeEvent {
  final Movie movie;

  SwipeRightEvent({
    required this.movie,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [movie];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to move the code calling `Provider.of(context)` into its own widget. As the error implies you can't use Provider to retrieve dependencies within the same BuildContext you used to set the Provider scope. Creating a new widget will also generate a new BuildContext.

If you really need to use `Provider.of(context)` in the same class you define MultiProvider you could use the [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) widget to generate a new context.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I created BlocProvider specifically in that widget where I use it.

Answer (score 0):

So, to solve this problem you should NOT use BlocProvider in main.dart. You should use it in that direct widget where BLoC Provider will be implemented. So I use it in one screen - recomendations, so I write it there like this

```
class RecomendationsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/recomendations';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => SwipeBloc()
          ..add(
            LoadMoviesEvent(
              movies: Provider.of<Movies>(context).movies,
            ),
          ),
        child: RecomendationsBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```